# Getting the location from a WebClient on a HTTP 302 Redirect?

Tags: c#, .net, http, sockets, https

I have a URL that returns a HTTP 302 redirect, and I would like to get the URL it redirects to.

The problem is that System.Net.WebClient seems to actually follow it, which is bad. HttpWebRequest seems to do the same.

Is there a way to make a simple HTTP Request and get back the target Location without the WebClient following it?

I'm tempted to do raw socket communication as HTTP is simple enough, but the site uses HTTPS and I don't want to do the Handshaking.

At the end, I don't care which class I use, I just don't want it to follow HTTP 302 Redirects :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On `HttpWebRequest` you can set `AllowAutoRedirect` to `false` to handle the redirect yourself.

Answer (score 23):

It's pretty easy to do

Let's assume you've created an HttpWebRequest called myRequest

```
// don't allow redirects, they are allowed by default so we're going to override
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

// send the request
HttpWebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();

// check the header for a Location value
if( response.Headers["Location"] == null )
{
  // null means no redirect
}
else
{
  // anything non null means we got a redirect
}
```

Excuse any compile errors I don't have VS right in front of me, but I've used this in the past to check for redirects.

Comment: Added the allow redirect to be false, since that is part of the original OP.

Comment: Typo: `AllowAutoRedirect` not `AutoAllowRedirect`

Answer (score 14):

The `HttpWebRequest` has a property [`AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) which you can set to false ([it is always true for `WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)), and then get the [`Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) HTTP header.

Comment: Good note, and it's hidden on the page right above the section that this link points to. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Also, for someone who just needs the new location, `HttpResponseMessage` has a `RequestMessage` property. Sometimes it can be useful, because `WebClient` doesn't support changing the `AllowAutoRedirect` property once it's been set.