# How can I get System.Net.Http.HttpClient to not follow 302 redirects?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Using [HttpClient from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient).

The app sends a post with client.PostAsync().  I'd like it to NOT follow 302 redirects.

how?

I figure I can just set `AllowAutoRedirect` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603837/48082).

But how do I get the `HttpWebRequest` used within a PostAsync() call?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One of the overloads of the `HttpClient` constructor takes a 
`WebRequestHandler` argument. The `HttpClient` class uses this
`WebRequestHandler` for sending requests.

The `WebRequestHandler` class provides a property called `AllowAutoRedirect` 
to configure the redirect behaviour. Setting this property to false
instructs the `HttpClient` to not follow redirect responses.

Here is a small code sample:

```
WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();

webRequestHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);

// Send a request using GetAsync or PostAsync

Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: ok thanks. That means I cannot specify 302-following behavior per call, correct?  It is per-handler, which implies, I guess, per-instance of HttpClient.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, it's per instance of the HttpClient. If you try to modify the AllowAutoRedirect property between two calls you will get an exception.

Answer (score 18):

To add to Hans' answer:

> WebRequestHandler derives from HttpClientHandler but adds properties
>   that generally only are available on full .NET. The WebRequestHandler
>   is not included in the System.Net.Http DLL but rather in
>   System.Net.Http.WebRequest DLL so you have to explicitly include that
>   as a reference in order to see it. Otherwise it won’t show up.

You can just spring for HttpClientHandler if you don't want to add new DLLs:

```
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/