# How does one configure HttpClient not to automatically redirect when it receives a 301 HTTP Status Code?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Consider an ASP.NET Web API service that redirects

```
public class ThisController : ApiController
{
    /* more methods */

    public override HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
        // Post requests should be made to "ThatController" instead.
        string uri = Url.Route("That", null);
        result.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Trying to verify that POST'ing data to "api/this" will redirect you to "api/that", I have the following test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PostRedirects()
{
    using (var client = CreateHttpClient("application/json"))
    {
        var content = CreateContent(expected, "application/json");
        using (var responseMessage = client.PostAsync("api/this", content).Result)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently, responseMessage.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(new Uri("https://api.example.com/api/that"), responseMessage.Headers.Location);
        }
    }
}

protected HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string mediaType)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.example.com/");
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue headerValue = MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse(mediaType);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(headerValue);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("gzip"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("deflate"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue(new ProductHeaderValue("MyProduct", "1.0")));
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024*1024*8;
    return client;
}

protected ObjectContent CreateContent(T model, string mediaType)
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
    MediaTypeFormatter mediaTypeFormatter = null;
    switch (mediaType)
    {
        case "application/json":
            mediaTypeFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            break;

        case "application/xml":
        case "text/xml":
            mediaTypeFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
            break;

        default:
            Assert.Fail();
            break;
    }

    return requestMessage.CreateContent(
        model,
        new[] { mediaTypeFormatter },
        new FormatterSelector());
}
```

What really happens that is that a HTTP Status Code is sent to the client with the correct Location header and that HttpClient then automatically performs a GET on that URI. As a result, my test never passes.

How do I configure the HttpClient not to automatically redirect when it receives a 301 so that I can verify that my server response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get System.Net.Http.HttpClient to not follow 302 redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453892/how-can-i-get-system-net-http-httpclient-to-not-follow-302-redirects)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() 
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this on a per-request basis without needing two separate `HttpClient` instances (i.e. one that allows redirects and one that does not)?

Comment: Maybe you need this: `handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 1`

Comment: @Dai No, that's not possible without reinventing the wheel unfortunately. But if you don't mind using a 3rd-party library [that's exactly what I did in Flurl 3.0](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/500).

Comment: Almost a decade later... how you can you set this up for a clean created using `TestServer.CreateClient()` ??

Answer (score 0):

To clarify this issue.  In client-side Blazor WASM the best you can do is cause the redirect to not happen, which may be good enough for your needs.  In this case you will get back a status code of zero with no response headers, no response content, etc.  It is **NOT POSSIBLE** to actually get the redirect status code (301, etc.), headers, etc. from the redirect response.

This is apparently due to the underlying JavaScript APIs used to implement HttpClientHandler:

- [How to get redirect url without following it using native fetch in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108923/how-to-get-redirect-url-without-following-it-using-native-fetch-in-javascript)

This makes coding an API client in browser hosted Blazor WebAssembly tricky if the API relies on redirect responses.  You could probably eventually get it to work via user-facing navigation actions rather than HttpClient, but ugg.

Hope this saves someone some time.

Some references on the topic:

- https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/2188
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44740

For anyone not running in a browser, here is a very nice example of doing this:

- https://gist.github.com/Delaire/3f1283dc6365d705dfd6ba24498d4993