# C# HttpClient 307 Destiny 2 SearchUser API

Tags: c#, http-status-code-307

I am working on a library for the Destiny 2 API and I am running into a problem at this spot. I wrote an extension for the `HttpClient.GetAsync` so that I can do `HttpClient.GetAsync<T>` and I am finding that in this extension I am not getting a success message because I get a

> 307 Temporary Redirect

I have run this same API request into Postman using my same api key and same path request and Postman doesn't get an error.

Extension Code:

```
public async static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this HttpClient Web, String Path)
        {
            var result = await Web.GetAsync(Path);
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var body = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body);
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

HttpClient Creation at creation of root ApiClass:

```
private HttpClient _Web { get; set; } = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        });
```

Comment: how did you instantiate the `HttpClient`? `HttpClient` uses `HttpClientHandler` under the hood and you can configure it [to either automatically follow redirects or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647245/4648586). also, just a piece of advice, those `await` better off having `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid unecessary deadlocks as you are *working on a library for the Destiny 2 API* (if its a separate class project from the application, do a `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

So after beating my head for awhile I found that I was passing this string `string path = $"User/SearchUsers?q={q}";` when it wanted this string `string path = $"User/SearchUsers/?q={q}";` notice the slash after SearchUsers... Their API I think is just misconfigured and that was very annoying..