# Retaining authorization header in RestSharp during redirects

Tags: c#, api, restsharp, unauthorized

I am using RestSharp to make a GET api call. The api call is authenticated through HTTP Basic authentication by passing the authorization header.

The server redirects the api call with a status code 307. My client code does handle the redirects but the authorization header is not passed to this redirected api call. This is done for valid reasons as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671822/537503). Hence I do get an unauthorized error.

How can I configure the RestClient to restore the authorization header?

```
var client = new RestClient("https://serverurl.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic Z3JvdXAxOlByb2otMzI1");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Tenant-Id", "4892");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added a check that resends the api request of receiving a 401 with the below code.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://serverurl.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic Z3JvdXAxOlByb2otMzI1");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Tenant-Id", "4892");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

//Resend the request if we get 401
int numericStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
if(numericStatusCode == 401) {
    var redirectedClient = new RestClient(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
    IRestResponse newResponse = redirectedClient.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(newResponse.ResponseStatus);
}
```