# Temporarily enable AllowAutoRedirect for HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, redirect, dotnet-httpclient

Is there any capability to temporarily turn on and turn off `AllowAutoRedirect` for `HttpClient`?

I should share one common `HttpClient` all through the app lifecycle and sometimes I want it to handle HTTP redirects but mostly no.

Comment: (Wrong link substitution) Add a [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, no easy way anyway. But don't take the HttpClient-as-a-singleton advice to too great of extremes. Having thousands of instances hanging around could risk socket exhaustion; having 2 instances won't. :)

I would opt for creating a wrapper class around the 2 instances you need and using that class as a singleton. This interface should give you the gist. (I figure implementation details are [well covered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10453892/62600) and not really relevant to your question.)

```
public interface IHttpClientManager
{
    public HttpClient WithRedirects { get; }
    public HttpClient WithoutRedirects { get; }
}
```