# Consuming API in .Net Core 3.1 returns with StatusCode: 302

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I am calling a Web API from my .Net Core 3.1 project but its giving me 302 response message. I have just created a simple controller and trying to retrieve result from a URL. The same API when called from Angular works fine.

Here is my angular code. It works fine and I get the result from "https://..../api/user".

```
try
    {
        strUrl = "https://..../api/user";
        return this.m_httpClient.get<any>(strUrl, { withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(map(data => data), catchError(this.handleError));
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        this.sendErrorEmail(err.message, "1");
    }
```

But when I try to call the same end point from my .Net Core project. I am getting following error message in apiResponse. Am I missing something? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
StatusCode: 302, ReasonPhrase: 'Moved Temporarily', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 23:53:52 GMT
Via: 1.1 HOEPRX01
Proxy-agent: 
Location: www.ticket.com:443/
Content-Length: 433
Content-Type: text/html
}
```

Here is my controller class.

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<User> userList = new List<User>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://..../api/user"))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(apiResponse);
            }
        }
        return View(userList);

        
    }

}
```

This is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

So I have updated my controller class based on answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453892/how-can-i-get-system-net-http-httpclient-to-not-follow-302-redirects) but I am still getting the 302 error message.

```
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();

webRequestHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://..../api/user"))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(apiResponse);
        }
    }
    return View(userList);

    
}
```

}

Comment: The dup talks about the opposite need, but the responses should give you what you need.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the answer mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453892/how-can-i-get-system-net-http-httpclient-to-not-follow-302-redirects but that didnt fix the issue for me.

Comment: We have this in the response `Location: www.ticket.com:443/` (notice the port number) and `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`. It seems that your app must be accessed by https. Does your .Net core app use https to access the API?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. I needed to use the full URL link to call the api from my .net core app. After adding .com in my api call, its now returning result.