# Unable to save image from URL in C# - using Webclient and DownloadFile();

Tags: c#, image, webclient

I am unable to download images from an RSS Feed, where the URL doesn't contain a filename.

**Example -**

Image URL I would like to download (it works if you click on it in a browser, but in code it doesn't work):

http://www.deviantart.com/download/286471805/

Using the code below I get a "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." error.  I have no idea why this isn't working.

Any ideas on how I can save these files?

```
    private void Start_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient MyDownloader = new WebClient();

            MyDownloader.DownloadFile(@"http://www.deviantart.com/download/286471805/", @"c:\test\");

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify a file name as the second argument, not the download directory:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.deviantart.com/download/174633066/",
                        @"c:\test\file.png");
}                                     ↑
```

Comment: The file name is not given in the RSS feed - which is actually the issue I am having (ie. RSS FEED: http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?q=gallery%3Amr--jack%2F9678590&type=deviation).  The RSS feed only contains the link I have with no filename. How can I get the filename?

Comment: Maybe you can use the id that is in the url. It's up to you which name do you want/need for that file.

Comment: It seems "the filename" you're referring to is the location to which your URL redirects. See: [Getting the location from a WebClient on a HTTP 302 Redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2603816/76217)